# How to get leading zeros displayed in the Vaadin DateTimePicker component?

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-flow

In my Vaadin Flow application, I'm using the [Vaadin DateTimePicker component](https://vaadin.com/components/vaadin-date-time-picker). If I select a date, it will be displayed without the leading zeros (e.g. "4.7.2021"). I would like the component to display the leading zeros (e.g. "04.07.2021"), but I could not find an API call to do so. Locale is Switzerland. Any ideas? I guess I'm missing a really easy solution to this all-day-problem…

Comment: Probably there's an open issue for this: https://github.com/vaadin/flow-components/issues/911

Comment: Thank you very much, @Hawk, I subscribed to the issue. There are some useful hints in the comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the EnhancedDatePicker https://vaadin.com/directory/component/enhanced-datepicker

There you can set pattern and even parsers. For example:

```
// how the date should be formatted
datePicker.setPattern("dd.MM.yyyy);

// allowed formats to enter the date
datePicker.setParsers("ddMMyy", "ddMMyyyy", "dd.MM.yy", "dd.MM.yyyy");
```

Comment: Nice! But to replace the `DateTimePicker`, I had to break my code up to use two components instead of one. That's not a big deal. :-)

Comment: How do you mean that?

Comment: My entity has a `LocalDateTime` and with the `DateTimePicker`I can bind that entity property directly, because the `DateTimePicker` handles both: date and time. The `EnhancedDatePicker` only handles `LocalDate`, not the time. So I had to rewrite the code a bit. Not a big deal.

Comment: If you have Date and Time we will have soon an EnhancedDateTimePicker ;-) Wait a few days.

Comment: Fantastic news!